# InstallShield 2011 error 7185 importing Japanese strings in the string table of basic MSI project

Tags: utf-8, localization, windows-installer, installshield

I am trying to import Japanese strings inside my "Basic MSI" project, it use to work before without any issues but now when I try to import some Japanese strings from a text file then it throws following error (I have changed some of the personal data from the error message.)

ISDEV : error -7185: The Japanese: 日本語 translation for string identifier IDS_XXXX_1111 includes characters that are not available on code page 932.

I think there are some of the characters inside the IDS_XXXX_1111 are not part of code page 932. How to detect those characters using some tool?

Also documentation mentions about changing some encoding settings to UTF-8 in InstallShield 2011, if you are aware then please guide me.

Thanks in advance

Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite way to detect such characters is with python. For example, reading a file like the InstallShield string tables in python 2.x:

```
import codecs
strings = codecs.open("strings.txt", "r", "UTF-16"):
for line in strings.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    try:
        line.encode("cp932")
    except UnicodeError:
        print "Can't encode: " + line.encode("cp932", "replace")
```

Your alternatives are to pinpoint the characters that cannot be represented on the relevant code page and replace them with ones that can, or to go to the Releases view and select yes for the Build UTF-8 Database setting.

Comment: +1 for the sample code. Thanks for sample code. This will definitely going to help me but right now I am able to resolve this with settings in InstallShield itself. I have answered the question. Thanks again

Comment: I have checked the Python script and it helped me to remove the characters not compatible with InstallShield. Thanks again.